# Shell scripts connected with pipe: trap termination of one script

Tags: shell-script, pipe, trap

I have two shell scripts, one runs on a server and writes some files to a temporary directory. This directory is then sent as a tar archive to stdout. At the end (or when it gets interrupted), the temporary directory should be deleted. The server script (saved e.g. in '~/get_dumps.sh') looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
temp_dir=`mktemp -d`
cd $temp_dir
trap "rm -r $temp_dir; exit" HUP INT TERM PIPE
for db in db1 db2 db3
  do
    pg_dump $db postgres > $db.sql
done
tar cJf - .
rm -r $temp_dir
```

The server script is called from a client with this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
temp_dir=`mktemp -d`
trap "rm -r $temp_dir; exit" HUP INT TERM PIPE
mkdir /tmp/dumps
ssh server '~/get_dumps.sh' | tar xJf - -C $temp_dir
ls $temp_dir
rm -r $temp_dir
```

If I run the client script and press Ctrl-C, neither on the client nor on the server the temporary directories are removed. Why does `trap` here not work?

Edit: First I have forgotten to add `set -e`.

Comment: Works fine for me. What OS & shell are you using (`/bin/sh`)? What point is the script at when you CTRL+C it? Have you tried running the script with debug output (`set -x`)?

Comment: @Patrick I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with dash. Thank you for the hint `set -x`. In the local test scripts, I had included `set -e` and forgotten to add it to the example code above. With `set -x` or without `set` it works. It seams that `set -e` is incompatible with trap.

Comment: @FabianHeller `set -e` is not incompatible with `trap`. Where does the script(s) terminate if you use `set -e`?

Comment: @Kusalananda I can press Ctrl-C on the client side either when the server script is executing `pg_dump` or `tar`. With or without `set -e`, the result is in both cases the same: The execution of `pg_dump` or `tar` stops immediately (and the script exits directly after `pg_dump` or `tar`). With `set -e(x)`, `trap` is not called, with `set -x` (or without `set`) it works as intended.

Comment: @FabianHeller First you say that it doesn't work with or without `set -e`. Then you say it works without `set -e`. Confused.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have meant that with `set -e` the `trap` command is not executed, else there are no differences.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `set -e`. If one presses e.g. Ctrl-c while mutiple commands are piped together, SIGINT is not sent to the script, but somewhere else. This creates an error which is handled by `set -e` and so the script exits directly. To use `set -e` reliable in scripts with pipes, one has to trap also `EXIT`:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
temp_dir=`mktemp -d`
cd $temp_dir
trap "rm -r $temp_dir; exit" HUP INT TERM PIPE EXIT
 for db in db1 db2 db3
   do
     pg_dump $db postgres > $db.sql
done
tar cJf - .
```

In this case, also the normal `exit` is handled by trap, which in many cases is anyway useful.